Bone A, that has a "child of constraint" to bone B, does not inherit the same rotation when I move the main parent bone C, how do you resolve this?
I have Bone A, which has a child of constraints targeting Bone B. Both Bones A and B are parented to Bone C, the root Bone. When I rotate the root bone, Bone A has a different pivot.
I constantly have to "Set Inverse" in the child of constraint of Bone A to align itself to the original rotation...
How do you resolve this issue?

i recommend describing what you want to achieve (end goal) instead of asking for technical aspects, because this might lead to a solution you don't think of .... ;)

You resolve this by unparenting A.
